# Ajax refresh and load php file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
setInterval(function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: "random_obiava.php",
        succes: function (){
            $("#random_ob").load("random_obiava.php").hide().fadeIn("slow");
            $("#random_ob").html("suc");
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#random_ob").html("err");
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Here is my code. I want to display random results on every X seconds. But this code always returns an error. I'm pretty sure the path to the file is correct so I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: what error? can you show?

Comment: Also why are you loading the file twice? The ajax call returns the data already. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: What do you mean twice? First one is to refresh the file and the next step is to show the content of the file. If i use only load() the content of the file remain the same and it's not randomized.

Comment: @k1tkat . Your spellings for "success" are wrong. its "success" Correct it. it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're wanting to do it's a long shot. By every X seconds you're making a *new* request to the server and this is a bad practice — your client will feeling your application running too slowly as the time passes. I suggest you to use a smart asynchronous technology like SignalR or NodeJS to perform this problem like you want.

By the way, to answer your question:

This fragment of code is **wrong**. You're using `succes` instead of  `success`. See:

```
succes: function (){
        $("#random_ob").load("random_obiava.php").hide().fadeIn("slow");
        $("#random_ob").html("suc");
}
```

The right way is:

```
success: function (){
    $("#random_ob").load("random_obiava.php").hide().fadeIn("slow");
    $("#random_ob").html("suc");
}
```

This is a syntax error. Pay more attention to your writing.